# Why does doubling the frame rate generate inconsistent frames?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

So I have a constant 59.94 fps `(i.e. 60000/1001)` video and when I attempt to extract one second:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input60fps.avi -ss 0 -t 1 -c:v huffyuv -an output60fps.avi
ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 ./output60fps.avi
```

it returns 1.001 seconds, which I now understand is appropriate since it is the multiple of the video's frame time `(60000/1001 seconds)` nearest to the requested duration.

Repeating this experiment on a 59.94 fps video that was previously converted from a 29.97 fps source, I'd expect similar results, but I'm seeing that's not actually the case:

```
ffmpeg -i input30fps.avi -vcodec huffyuv -r 60000/1001 -an output60fps.avi
ffmpeg -i ./output60fps.avi -ss 0 -t 1 -c:v huffyuv -an test.avi
ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 ./test.avi
```

This actually results in 0.984317 seconds.

Why is this behavior different? Is there some way for me to control how the total frames get distributed evenly such that each boundary occurs every 60000/1001 milliseconds? My expectation here is that since I'm just doubling the frame rate, I should expect a frame every 1001/60000 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AVI is a variable frame rate muxer. In addition to `-r`, you need to enable constant frame rate so

```
ffmpeg -i input30fps.avi -vcodec huffyuv -r 60000/1001 -vsync cfr -an output60fps.avi
```

Comment: Works great! I'm finally now able to get the precise timings I was looking for :)